# Loading Query Variables Into Included Template Pages

Tags: django

I'm just wondering if there is a simple way to do this.

Say I have index.html:

```
<HTML>

    {% include 'sidebar.html' %}

</HTML>
```

and a sidebar.html page:

```
<b>{{company}}</b>
```

The view in views.py for the index.html includes a context such as:

```
context['company'] = Company.objects.get(id=3)
```

My question is as follows. That sidebar and that variable will be loaded into many pages and I would rather not load the context into every view that uses the company name. I just want to include it once for the sidebar and have it included each time.

So in essence, I want to extract it out of every view that uses it to reduce redundancy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own context processor:

```
def company_context(request):
    return {
        'company':Company.objects.get(id=3),
    }
```

Add your new context processor to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR in settings
eg:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "path.to.context.processor.company_context",
```

)

after which you use the render as usual in the view :

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

if you don't use render make sure you use RequestContext

[Django Docs Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: That is most helpful. Thank you sir!